# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: NL Exception was generated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, datastax

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 while I am trying to connect the oracle db using my spark program

> Spark Program

```
val o_url =//"jdbc:oracle:thin: etc ... it is correct and working
val query  ="( SELECT 1 FROM DUAL ) T";
val dfReader   = spark.read.format("jdbc")
       .option("url", o_url)
       .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
       .option("user", "ABC")
       .option("password", "ZYX")
       .option("fetchsize","10000")

val ss = dfReader
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("schema","LDF")
                .option("dbtable", query)
                .load();

println(" Table Count : "+ ss.count());
spark.close();
```

> Ofcource I added the "ojdbc14.jar" jar in my class path.

I am getting below error

**Error**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: NL Exception was generated
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
```

what is wrong here ? How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It was with 
val o_url =//"jdbc:oracle:thin: etc ... it is correct and working

It was earlier

> val o_url ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)... 
>   ; ";

I corrected it as below by removing ";" inside quotes.

> val o_url ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)... 
>   ";